# kotlin - how to reuse value of one parameter in another parameter

Tags: kotlin

i've created an object but for one of the parameters the creation is complex. after i create it i want to use that same value for another parameter. let me show you an example simply:

```
MyModel(convenienceFee = raw.data?.fee,
           data = raw.data?.order?.map {/*complex operation that returns a list*/} ?: emptyList(),
            summary = createSummaryFrom(data), //compiler wont allow me using data here
            )
```

the createSummaryFrom is irrelevant it just takes a list and does some operations on it.

but the issue is i am not able to use "data" on the last line. it says its a unresolved field. how can i use the value of a already declared parameter in another parameter ?

clearly i can move the call outside of the declaration but wondering why i can do it inside while declaring it.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use a variable? Here `data` is just a parameter name, that's why you can't use it, it's just a hint for the programmer.

Comment: yah i can use a variable , actually was wondering if there was some shortcut i did not know about to get this done.

Comment: No, unless you change your function signature to have a default value for `summary` parameter equal to `createSummaryFrom(data)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `.run` or a `.let` scope function could be used to achieve something similar, but the reference to another parameter name is forbidden. I should note this code could also be achieved through typical use of variables, but, syntactically, a `.let` is more inline with what you desire.

```
val model: MyModel = raw.data.let { rawData ->
    (rawData?.order?.map { ... } ?: emptyList()).let { transformedData ->
        MyModel(
            convenienceFee = rawData?.fee,
            data = transformedData,
            summary = createSummaryFrom(transformedData)
        )
    }
}
```

If you would like, you can read about Kotlin's five scope functions [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html).

**Edit upon valid feedback regarding readability:**

Scope functions should be used appropriately. Outside of the scope of this question, I would prefer the following:

```
val rawData = raw.data
val transformedData = rawData?.order?.map { ... } ?: emptyList()

val model = MyModel(
    convenienceFee = rawData?.fee,
    data = transformedData,
    summary = createSummaryFrom(transformedData)
)
```

Comment: Honestly I have used Kotlin for years, and yet I find this pretty complicated for something that could be done with just 2 variables. We should really be cautious about readability when using scoping functions.

Comment: I agree; this isn't readable. I tailored my answer to the asker's desires and explicitly noted this could also be achieved through the typical use of variables.

Comment: I find my answer appropriate because the asker's underlying concern regards variable scopes, so I provided an example addressing the topic and referenced the appropriate documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to reuse a value would be the obvious: use local variables. But I guess you know that.

Another option would be to define your computation for `summary` as a default value for it, at the declaration site of the `MyModel` class. There, it is allowed to use the value of the parameter `data`:

```kotlin
class MyModel(
    val convenienceFee: Double,
    val data: DataType,
    val summary: Summary = createSummaryFrom(data),
)
```

Then when you actually instantiate your class, you don't need to provide `summary`:

```kotlin
MyModel(
    convenienceFee = raw.data?.fee,
    data = raw.data?.order?.map {/*complex operation that returns a list*/} ?: emptyList()
)
```